# Cereal 1.2.0 - "looser throw specifier" error using JSON or XML archive

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, throw, cereal

I just moved on Cereal 1.2.0 (moved from 1.1.2), and I obtain a compilation error when using JSONOutputArchive or XMLOutputArchive (i.e. including either "cereal/archives/json.hpp" or "cereal/archives/xml.hpp")

```
std::stringstream outParamStream;

foo.enable = true;
foo.size = 12;

{
  cereal::JSONOutputArchive outArchive(outParamStream);
  outArchive(foo);
}

doSomeStuffWith(inParamStream->str());
```

Exact errors are :

```
..sources/ext/cereal/archives/json.hpp:158: error: looser throw specifier for 'virtual cereal::JSONOutputArchive::~JSONOutputArchive()'

..sources/ext/cereal/archives/json.hpp:402: error: looser throw specifier for 'virtual cereal::JSONInputArchive::~JSONInputArchive()'

..sources/ext/cereal/cereal.hpp:584: error:   overriding 'virtual cereal::InputArchive<cereal::JSONInputArchive>::~InputArchive() noexcept (true)'
```

I compile using `-std=c++11`, with gcc version 4.7.3

I do need a `std::string` so I can't move to binary or portable_binary archive.

Is anyone else experienced this error using Cereal 1.2.0 ?

Did I miss something (I can't believe they released such a thing as the header does not even compile) ?

Thanks !

Comment: If this is a real issue maybe you should put on Cereal Github issue tracker ?

Comment: I do not know if this is a "real issue" (i.e. not my fault), that's why I asked if someone else (more experienced) have the problem too. But, ok, I guess I can try asking on he issue tracker.

Comment: Opened as [#311](https://github.com/USCiLab/cereal/issues/311#issuecomment-231459121), tagged as a **bug** . Thanks !